# VBA Application-defined or object-define error in MS-Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to develop an MS Access project that should search through records based on multiple search criteria like start and end date, country of event, event name etc. But I don't quite understand why I am having this error:

```
    Private Sub CommandSearch_Click()
 Dim strReport As String 'Name of report to open.
    Dim strField As String 'Name of your date field.
    Dim strMessage As String 'Message on no data for selection.
    Dim varWhere As String 'Where condition for OpenReport.

    ' Const conDateFormat = "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#"
    Const conDateFormat = "\#dd\/mm\/yyyy\#"

    ' strReport = "RB_Events"
    strField = "[Event_StartDate]"
    varWhere = ""

    ' ================================================================================
    ' CHECK FOR DATE RANGE
    ' ================================================================================
    If IsNull(Me.txtEvent_StartDate) Then
        If Not IsNull(Me.txtEvent_EndDate) Then  'End date, but no start.
            varWhere = "(" & strField & " <= " & Format(Me.txtEvent_EndDate, conDateFormat) & ") "
        Else
            'neither start nor end dates, do nothing to varWhere
        End If
    Else
        If IsNull(Me.txtEvent_EndDate) Then  'Start date, but no End.
            varWhere = "(" & strField & " >= " & Format(Me.txtEvent_StartDate, conDateFormat) & ") "
        Else 'Both start and end dates present.
            varWhere = "(" & strField & " Between " & Format(Me.txtEvent_StartDate, conDateFormat) _
            & " AND " & Format(Me.txtEvent_EndDate, conDateFormat) & ")"
        End If
    End If

    ' =============================================================
    ' CHECK FOR data in fields
    ' ================================================================================

      Dim strSQL As String

        ' Check for anything like event name
    If Me.txtEvent_Name <> "" Then
        varWhere = varWhere & "[Event_Name] Like '*" & Me.txtEvent_Name & "*' AND "
    End If

  'Drop the last " AND " from the string
    If Right(strSQL, 5) = " AND " Then
        strSQL = Left(strSQL, Len(strSQL) - 5)
    End If

    'next add the where to the front of the string if the user has entered something in at least one field
    If strSQL <> "False" Then
        If varWhere = "" Then
            varWhere = strSQL
        Else
            varWhere = varWhere & " AND " & strSQL
        End If
    End If

    '================================================================================

    Debug.Print varWhere

    If varWhere <> "" Then
        'Update the list box row source

Forms!F_EVENTS.RowSource = "SELECT * FROM Q_EVENTS WHERE " & varWhere

    Else
        'Update the list box row source
       Forms!F_EVENTS.RowSource = "SELECT * FROM Q_EVENTS"

    End If

    ' Requery the list box
    Forms!F_EVENTS.Requery

Exit_cmdSearch_Click:
   Exit Sub

Err_cmdSearch_Click:
    MsgBox "You did not fill in any data", vbCritical, "No data"
    Resume Exit_cmdSearch_Click
End Sub
```

Comment: It should be: `Const conDateFormat = "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#"` or `Const conDateFormat = "\#yyyy\/mm\/dd\#"`, but where is the error raised?

Comment: Forms!F_EVENTS.RowSource = "SELECT * FROM Q_EVENTS WHERE " & varWhere

Answer (score 0):

RowSource is for a combo/listbox. So:

```
Forms!F_EVENTS.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM Q_EVENTS WHERE " & varWhere –
```

Comment: Okay. Following that correction I have these two error: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '([Event_StartDate] >=#05/18/2018#) AND'

Comment: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[Event_Name] Like '*sar*' AND AND'

Comment: Yes. An AND must always be followed by a criteria. Correct that.